# Remove white border of CButton

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, border, cbutton

How do I remove the white border on a CButton?

I want to put two buttons, each having a BMP image, side by side so that they create a single image without having a white gap between, but when I overlap the two buttons I get a white border from either. I tried with `DrawBorder(FALSE, TRUE);` but it doesn't work.

How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with CBitmapButton.  If I recall, it does not have any border unless you create one as part of the bitmap images.

Comment: Is it possible to use 'CBitmapButton' in a non-dialog window? Coz, 'm_bitmapButton.SubclassDlgItem(501,this);' makes my application to crash (as my button with id 501 is not from a dialog).