# Remove visual click effect of CButton

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, click, cbutton

Is there any way of removing the visual effect of clicking a CButton?

I want to put two CButtons with BMPs side by side so that they form a bigger image, but I want to remove the visual effect of the click - that is the image being pressed. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm fascinated to know why you want to do this... :)

Comment: Why buttons? Just use two static controls with `SS_BITMAP | SS_NOTIFY` style. Static controls don't produce any visual effects, when clicked or otherwise (hence "static").

Comment: Based on this question and [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23935818/2065121) this sounds like [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) - maybe its better to explain what you want to achieve, it sounds to me like you want clickable areas on an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same image for the Up and Down states of the button.  That way it would look the same whether pressed or not.  You will have to use the `CBitmapButton` class,  however, which derives from `CButton`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3y45xs0.aspx

There are 4 states of the button:  UP, DOWN, FOCUS, DISABLED and each can have its own image (or not).  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y6acs49.aspx